# How can I optimize this mysql stored proc?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure in mysql and it works but it's running so slow like 120 seconds. I need it to be faster than that.
How can i optimize this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_test`( IN merchantId int, IN startDate VARCHAR(50),IN endDate VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT
    inventory.sku AS 'SKU',
    inventory.description AS 'Description',
    inventory_category.name as 'Category',
    inventory_sub_category.name as 'Sub Category',
    IFNULL(tbl_ticket.price,0) AS 'Unit Price',
    IFNULL(tbl_ticket.quantity_total,0) AS 'Total Issued',
    IFNULL(ROUND(tbl_ticket.price,2),0) * IFNULL(tbl_ticket.quantity_total,0) AS 'Gross Amount',
    IFNULL(tbl_ticket.promo_code_discount, 0 ) AS 'Total Discount',
    ROUND((IFNULL(tbl_ticket.price,0) * IFNULL(tbl_ticket.quantity_total,0) ) -  IFNULL(tbl_ticket.promo_code_discount, 0 ),2) AS 'Net Amount'
    FROM inventory
    LEFT JOIN inventory_category ON inventory.inventory_category_id = inventory_category.id
    LEFT JOIN inventory_sub_category ON inventory.inventory_sub_category_id = inventory_sub_category.id
    LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT inventory.sku, inventory.price, channel.merchant_id, SUM(ticket.quantity_total) as 'quantity_total',
      SUM(ticket.promo_code_discount) as 'promo_code_discount'
    FROM inventory
    JOIN  v_transaction_items_details ON inventory.sku = v_transaction_items_details.item_name
    JOIN ticket on ticket.id = v_transaction_items_details.ticket_id
    JOIN transaction ON ticket.transaction_id = transaction.id
    JOIN channel ON channel.sub_agent_id = ticket.reseller_id
    WHERE CAST(transaction.time as DATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
    AND transaction.payment_status = 2
    AND ticket.level = 1
    AND ticket.type = 1
    GROUP BY inventory.sku, inventory.price, channel.merchant_id) tbl_ticket on tbl_ticket.sku = inventory.sku
    WHERE inventory.status = 1 AND (inventory.merchant_id = merchantId OR tbl_ticket.merchant_id = merchantId)
    GROUP BY inventory.sku,inventory.description,inventory_category.name,inventory_sub_category.name;
END
```

I appreciate anyone that could help me on this.
If i were to use caching how does that work?

Comment: Do you want to say that the same SELECT is more fast when executed immediately?

Comment: You need to share the explain for the select with certain parameters and you need to share the indexes and their fields you have on the underlying table. You also have to describe what the query is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to troubleshoot this kind of performance trouble is to work directly with the query in the SP. Start with any subqueries, optimize them, and work your way out to the top level query. Only then work on the SP itself.

You have a subquery containing this WHERE clause.

```
WHERE CAST(transaction.time as DATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
AND transaction.payment_status = 2
```

This has a problem: it cannot exploit any index on the `time` column. Try refactoring it like so.

```
WHERE startDate <= transaction.time
  AND transaction.time < endDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND transaction.payment_status = 2
```

Notice the `<`, not `<=`, at the end of the date/time range.

Then create a compound index on those two columns, putting the equality-search column first and the range-search column second. Like this.

```
ALTER TABLE transaction ADD INDEX status_time 
    (payment_status, time);
```

You didn't tell us much about your data, so this is a guess. But range searches of the form

```
function(column) BETWEEN this AND that
```

are usually a good place to start working on query performance. The use of a function to modify a column value in a WHERE clause often defeats the use of indexes.  Read about *sargability*.

Also, the use of BETWEEN on date/time values is often a [code smell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): a hint that something is worth checking for mistakes or confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Do those Joins need to be `LEFT`?  A `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery is a performance problem.

So is `OR`.  Switching to a `UNION` *may* be the solution.  (But the `GROUP BY` adds complexity.)

What is the datatype of `transaction.time`?  If it is `DATE`, then the `CAST` is unnecessary.  On the other hand, if `startDate and endDate are` DATEs`, then` DATETIME`might work well.  Let's see`SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Meanwhile, these indexes *may* help:

```
inventory:  INDEX(status, merchant_id, inventory_category_id)
inventory:  INDEX(sku,  price)
channel:  INDEX(sub_agent_id,  merchant_id)
ticket:  INDEX(level, type, id)
v_transaction_items_details:  INDEX(item_name,  ticket_id)
transaction:  INDEX(time, payment_status, id)
```

And, use `DATE` for dates!:  `IN startDate VARCHAR(50)`

That may be the reason why the Stored Proc is slower than the query.  Also, when you tested outside the SP, did you use literals for start/enddate?  That may be a difference, too.

Comment: I added a couple of fo paragraphs.